# How to call method of React component outside of a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal in my React one page app. I made a class component of modal and render it in some place on the page. I need to call it from many other pages in app this modal.
My modal class:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalShow: false,
    }
  }
  setModalShow(state){
   this.setState({modalShow: state});
  }      
  render(){...}
}
```

State of modal I keep in modal class. I want to show modal by changing state from outside Modal class. For examle something like

```
import Modal from './Modal'
...
Modal.setModalShow(true)
```

But Modal its a class, but I need to call setModalShow in instance of a class. And I don't understand how to do such a thing in React true way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of behavior requires passing down that function as a child property, Like this:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  setModalShow(state){
   this.props.showModal(true);
  }      

  render(){
    ...
  }
}
```

And wherever you use the modal, there should be the showing state like:

```
class ModalWrapper extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    }
  }

  showModal(state){
    this.setState({modalShow: state});
  }      

  render(){
    return (<Modal showModal={showModal} />);
  }
}
```

Comment: So the only way is to keep state outside of my Modal, right? I did't thought of this way. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

While you can, as other suggests, pass a function that will allow you to register the method to another component, this is probably not the "React" way to open a modal outside of the component (meaning that there are ways that will, I believe, be clearer to write in React than this). I would suggest either making the open state a prop or maintain the modal state in a react context (or even pass the opening function as a context, if more things happen in it than simply opening the modal), which will allow you to avoid prop drilling.

You can read about the context API in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html. Note that it is far simpler to use as a hook in a functional component, but it works fine with classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the method `setModalShow` from `Modal` to one of its children, and then the child component would call `this.props.setModalShow(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

I desided to use Redux. In [Motivation](https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation) is described my problem.